# Trying to add as SUM with Case to cognos

Tags: sql, cognos

I am trying to add a Sum to a data item with a case statement. I am trying to create the results in cognos from the SQL query below.

```
Select 
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN reas_desc = 'misapplied funds' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Misapplied
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN reas_desc = 'lump sum payment' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Lumps
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN proc_desc = 'title/registration' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Title/Reg"
```

I want the end product to have 3 columns titled "Misapplied", "lumps", and "title/Reg"with the total of those items. The SQL code works perfectly but I need to build in cognos for others to view and use.

Comment: i doubt the query works as the first column should not have a comma also the table is missing

Comment: SELECT 

  SUM(CASE WHEN reas_desc = 'misapplied funds' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Misapplied
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN reas_desc = 'lump sum payment' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Lumps
  ,SUM(CASE WHEN proc_desc = 'title/registration' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "Title/Reg"
  , "total" - "Lumps"- "Misapplied"-"Title/Reg" As "Other Needed For SLA"
  
FROM SPOT_BVAL.CCS_Workflow a

Comment: that was a copy error. It works just fine ;) bahahah Any thoughts on how to add it to cognos?

Comment: `total(case when [reas_desc] = 'misapplied funds then 1 else - end)`

Comment: Thanks Andrew! This looks like it should work, I am putting it in the output of a join. When I put this in the expression it errors out when trying to generate the SQL though it validates in the expression box. Am I missing somthing?

Comment: Are you getting an error? What is it? Sometimes I forget to add data source in the properties of the SQL. Did you do that?

Comment: Using the `total()` function in this context may not be appropriate.  Kyle didn't say this was specifically for a group summary in a list or an edge summary in a crosstab.  I'm pretty sure he just wants to aggregate the results.

Answer (score 0):

You define your first data item like this:

```
CASE WHEN reas_desc = 'misapplied funds' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

From that you should be able to figure out the rest.

**Apparently more detail is needed:**

Data item 1:

Expression: `CASE WHEN reas_desc = 'misapplied funds' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Name:  `Misapplied`

Detail Aggregation:  `Total`

Data item 2:

Expression:  `CASE WHEN reas_desc = 'lump sum payment' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Name:  `Lumps`

Detail Aggregation:  `Total`

Data item 3:

Expression:  `CASE WHEN proc_desc = 'title/registration' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`

Name:  `Title/Reg`

Detail Aggregation:  `Total`